# Text label next to jquery slider (in div of unknown width)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-slider

Inside a parent div, I want to have a text label on the left, and a slider (using jQuery UI) on the right.

I wish the slider to take up all the available space, and unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5899535/text-label-next-to-jquery-ui-slider), the parent div is of unknown width.

So conceptually it should be something like this ([jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jgnnr/4/) with broken attempt):

```
<div id="parentDiv" style="width:100%">
<span>Unicorn awesomeness:</span><div id="unicornSlider"></div>
</div>
```

But I can't get anything easily that works on Chrome, FF3 and IE8. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting the width using jQuery:

```
$('#unicornSlider')
    .width($('#parentDiv').width() -$('#parentDiv span').width() - 20)
    .slider()
```

I'ev updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jgnnr/10/) to include this. (I've also had to change the width of the parent div to be 90%, as 100% + padding was bigger than the window).

**Update:** I have noticed that this keeps that width when the browser window is resized. You could recalculate the width with `$(window).resize(function)`.